# return type of map array in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have this function

```
export const handleSortableColumns = (headerKeys: string[], sortKeys: object): string[] => {
  if (!headerKeys) return [];

  return headerKeys.map((key: string): any => sortKeys[key] || null);
};
```

so **headerKeys** parameter takes `list of string`
**sortKeys** parameter should take an `object` but I think it's wrong to put object type and I can't define type or interface because each time it will be different properties. should I specify generic type ? how I can do that ?
also the return type will be a list of strings that contains null values as well so what should be return type + using any type is forbidden

Answer (score 1):

For the `sortKeys` you could do it like this

```js
interface ISortKeys {
  [key: string]: string
}
```

For the return type you could use

```js
(string|null)[]
```

Comment: I get error on line `return headerKeys.map((key: string): any => sortKeys[key] || null);` 
Type '(string | null)[][]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
  Type '(string | null)[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Comment: I'm not able to recreate your error, could you update the question with your current code? Maybe an example on how you use it?

Answer (score 0):

I switched `sortKeys` and `headerKeys`. This helps usability because the type checker immediately knows on what object you're operating on. I also made headerKeys variadic but you can revert it back to a regular array, if you prefer that.

```
const handleSortableColumns = <T>(sortKeys: T, ...headerKeys: (keyof T & string)[]): (string | null)[] => {
    if (!headerKeys) return [];
    const result = headerKeys.map(key => sortKeys[key] || null);
    return result as (string | null)[];
}
```

.

```
handleSortableColumns({ a: '1', b: 2 }, 'a', 'X');
```

Is now a type error. But this doesn't save you from

```
handleSortableColumns({ a: '1', b: 2 }, 'a', 'b');
```

Including more strict return type checks quickly turns into an unreadable type soup. I'd recommend using run time checks, `filter` or `throw`, instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters to infer the types of the input values, and then use those generics to create an array return type which represents the subset of values in the object that can be indexed by the values in the input array (or null). Here's an example:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#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)

```ts
function handleSortableColumns <
  Keys extends readonly string[],
  ValueMap extends Record<string, unknown>,
>(headerKeys: Keys, valueMap: ValueMap): (ValueMap[Extract<keyof ValueMap, Keys[number]>] | null)[] {
  return headerKeys.map(
    key => (valueMap[key] ?? null) as ValueMap[Extract<keyof ValueMap, Keys[number]>] | null
  );
}

const keys = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const;

const map = {
  a: 1,
  c: false,
  d: 'hello world',
};

const result = handleSortableColumns(keys, map);
    //^? const result: (number | boolean | null)[]

console.log(result); // [1, null, false]
```

Compiled JS from the TS Playground:

```js
"use strict";
function handleSortableColumns(headerKeys, valueMap) {
    return headerKeys.map(key => (valueMap[key] ?? null));
}
const keys = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const map = {
    a: 1,
    c: false,
    d: 'hello world',
};
const result = handleSortableColumns(keys, map);
//^?
console.log(result); // [1, null, false]
```